# "Break" ou "return false"?

Tags: javascript

Dentro de uma função há uma estrutura de repetição, quanto a economia de processamento, qual é o melhor?

**JavaScript**

```
function minhaFuncao(boom){
    for(i = boom; i > 10; i--){
        if(i < 0){
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

ou

```
function minhaFuncao(boom){
    for(i = boom; i > 10; i--){
        if(i < 0){
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Existe alguma outra forma ainda mais econômica?

Comment: Depende. Se voc"e quiser apenas interromper o loop, `break` é a melhor opção. Se você quiser interromper o loop **E** já abortar qualquer lógica da função, retornando um valor `return` é melhor pois atua nas duas pontas.

Comment: Mas... esse código nunca vai entrar no `if`!

Comment: O boom pode chegar menor que 10.

Comment: Nesse caso o corpo do `for` não chega a executar nenhuma vez.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Existem 3 opções que dependem um pouco daquilo que pretende. Note que o seu código nunca entra no `if` pois a condição dentro do `for` não permite valores negativos. O seu `for` corre pela ultima vez quando o `i` é 1 e fazendo `i--` dá-lhe um ultimo valor de `0` e o seu `if`procura `<0`. Tendo dito isso as opções são:

### break;

O break **pára o loop** e segue para a primeira linha de código **depois** do loop. Se não precisar de percorrer todas as iterações de um `loop` mas precisar de correr código depois do loop, use esta opção.

### continue;

O continue salta para a próxima iteração do loop.Se não precisar de correr todo o código de uma iteração específica, mas precisa de todas as iterações, use esta opção.

### return;

O return pára a função em que está e retorna o valor a seguir à palavra "return". Esteja dentro de um loop, switch ou outro a função pára imediatamente e não executa a linha seguinte ao return.

---

**Quanto a economia de processamento** depende do que precisa. O mais económico é o return pois é o mais poderoso e garante que mais nenhum código é corrido. A sugestão é usar sempre o mais defenitivo e que não limite o código que pretende correr.

**É util usar estes métodos para economizar processamento?** Sim, sem dúvida.

Answer (score 2):

O [break](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_break.asp) no caso do `for` vai servir para interromper o *loop* do `for`, sendo assim pela função passada mais ideal. Se após o for tiver código ele será executado normalmente, ou seja, somente o loop será interrompido. Nesse caso não vai implicar nada em processamento, porque, é interrompido o loop.

O [return false](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_form_validation.asp) para totalmente a execução do seu código e consequentemente o processamento.

***Exemplo:*** [**Demo**](http://fiddle.jshell.net/Mpv57/)

```
function Imprimir(p) {
    var texto = ""
    var i;
    var demo = document.getElementById("demo");
    for (i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {        
        if (i == 6) {
            if (p === 1) 
            { 
                break; 
            } 
            else 
            { 
                return false;
            }
        }
        texto += "Numero: " + i + "<br>";
    }   
    demo.innerHTML += texto + "<br>";
}
Imprimir(1);
Imprimir(1);
Imprimir(2);
```

Os dois primeiro serão impressos, porque, foi utilizado `break` enquando o último ele para a execução da função nem exibe resultado.

Comment: Sim, mas implica em alguma diferença no processamento?

Comment: @Patrick eu editei.